# .htaccess rule for codeIgniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter-2

I need an .htaccess rule for the following criteria. I am working in codeIgniter

I need to change:

http://project.com/projectname/controller_folder/sub_folder_in_controller

to:

http://project.com/projectname/sub_folder_in_controller

So if any thing starts with `/controller_folder/sub_folder_in_controller`, I need it to be converted to `/sub_folder_in_controller`.

Please help, thanks in advance

-Vamsi

Answer (score 0):

By default, codeigniter allows you to organize your controllers in one-level subfolders.
Take a look in the [controller user guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#subfolders).